# How to disable weak SSH cipher in CentOS 7

Tags: encryption, ssh

I am running CentOS 7.9 (server edition)

I have been searching online for some help on how to disable weak ssh cypher. However, I do not seem to be able to fix the issue. Qualys scans keeps reporting weak cipher in ssh service. I followed some recommendations (i.e: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-weak-cipher-and-insecure-hmac-algorithms-in-ssh-services-for-centos-rhel-6-and-7/) online without any luck.

Here is what my /etc/ssh/sshd_config looks like

```
# Addresses Qualys QID 38739 Deprecated SSH Cryptographic Settings (CentOS 6)
## Changed this line:
##ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
## to this line:
ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

Go to below directory and uncomment the below line

**Vi /etc/sysconfig/sshd**

Uncomment

**CRYPTO_POLICY=**

**Step 2:**

Go to the below directories and append the below lines at the end of file

**vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config**

**KexAlgorithms** curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

**Ciphers** chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr

**MACs** hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com

**Step 3:**

**systemctl restart sshd**

Comment: Thank you @abidbajwa for your help.

I made the changes as you suggested. However, security came back at me saying the "Deprecated SSH Cryptographic Settings is still on the server.

I honestly do not know what to do anymore.

Comment: Hi @Legio06 please check ssh properties at this path. /etc/sysconfig/sshd

CRYPTO_POLICY=

if it's commentented uncomment it and restart ssh services